# Azure Durable Function Fan Out Fan In suggestion

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I just want to get your opinion regarding on the best approach for my scenario. I have a list of Contacts to process which can be 100 or more. For each contact, it may take less than a minute to be completed.

I have tried both Function Chaining and Fan-Out/Fan-In patterns. Function Chaining takes longer to process and definitely will throw Time Out if processing takes more than 5 minutes, which can happen. Fan-out/Fan-in on the other hand, processes contacts in parallel but it can only process 100 records per instance [not sure about the reason]. I am not 100% sure about the impact in terms of scalability.

```
//Function Chaining
var contacts = context.CallActivityAsync<List<Contacts>>("GetContacts", null);
await context.CallActivityAsync("ProcessContacts", contacts);

//Fan-out/Fan-in pattern
var contacts = context.CallActivityAsync<List<Contacts>>("GetContacts", null);
foreach(var contact in contacts){
    await context.CallActivityAsync("ProcessContact", contact);
}
```

I honestly want to go with Fan-Out/Fan-In but again, I'm not sure about the impact.

I just want to get an opinion about this on which pattern should I choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have above isn't Fan Out, in order to Fan out you need to create all the activity requests at once and then wait for them to all finish. In this way the consumption plan will keep spawning instances until all the work it done.

Try changing your Fan Out code to something like this:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var contact in contacts)
{
    tasks.Add(context.CallActivityAsync("ProcessContact", contact));
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

This creates 1 activity task for each contact and places them in a queue for the function to process; then it waits for them all to finish.

Once you see this running you will then want to look at [maxConcurrentActivityFunctions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json-v1) depending on how CPU etc. intensive your processing is you may only want to process say 5 contacts in parallel on a single instance.

You could try setting this to 1 initially and then say 10 and see what the speed difference is, you will find the more contacts you have and the smaller the maxConcurrentActivityFunctions is the faster the Consumption plan will create new instances but that might not be efficient speed wise so you need to find the balance between optimal use of a single CPU instance and maxConcurrentActivityFunctions.

I recommend you connect this to an Application Insights instance and then look at the Live Metrics which will show you things like CPU/Memory usage and how many instances are being created.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Simon,

Sorry. Your code was actually my code. I just written the code on the fly while putting up this question that I forgot adding Tasks to it. 

I'll keep this in mind and check the flow via Application Insights. Think I would go with Fan Out now. Thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: No problem, Fan Out will definitely be faster once you get the settings tuned